# SWIG & MarshalDirectiveException: Marshaling to and from COM interface pointers isn't supported

Tags: c#, pinvoke, marshalling, swig

I'm using SWIG to store C# managed callback functions inside an unmanaged class. Then, I'm calling an unmanaged method (say, e.g., `Execute()`) that will call all managed functions passed earlier. However, my program throws the following exception every time `Execute()` is called:

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException: Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Marshaling to and from COM interface pointers isn't supported).`

I was not familiar with `COM` interfaces [until read this introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/what-is-a-com-interface-) nor with `UnmanagedType` [enums](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype?view=net-7.0). Though I received others exception messages after adding some potential `enums` in the `PINVOKE` file, I had no clue if I was in the right direction.

File callback.h:

```
#include <vector>

namespace test {
class Model {
 private:
  std::vector<void (*)(Model*)> functions;

 public:
  virtual void AddFunction(void (*func)(Model*)) { functions.push_back(func); }

  virtual void Execute() {
    for (int m = 0; m < functions.size(); ++m) functions[m](this);
  }

  Model() {}
  virtual ~Model() {}
};
};  // namespace test
```

File callback.i:

```
%module callback
%typemap(csclassmodifiers) SWIGTYPE "public partial class"

%typemap(csclassmodifiers) test::Model "public partial class"

%typemap(csin) void (*)(test::Model*) "$csinput"
%typemap(cstype) void (*)(test::Model*) "Model.MakerDelegate";
%typemap(imtype) void (*)(test::Model*) "Model.MakerDelegate";
%typemap(csvarout) void (*)(test::Model*) %{
get {
  return $imcall;
} %}
%{
#include "callback.h"
%}
%include "callback.h"
```

C# project file with `Main` method:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class Model
    {
        public delegate void MakerDelegate(Model model);
    }

    public class Bar
    {
        public static void Foo(Model model)
        {
            // Want to access model from here...
            Console.WriteLine("dog");
            Console.WriteLine(1 + 4);
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var seila = new Model();
            seila.AddFunction(Foo);
            seila.Execute();
        }
    }
};
```

How can I get rid of this exception? Thanks in advance.